# Get whole string literal under cursor

Tags: vim

Vim has `expand("<cword>")` to get the "word" under the cursor. If the cursor is on a quoted string literal, how would you define a function to get everything between the quotes?

Given this scenario:

```
foo = "this string has spaces"
          ^ cursor is here
```

I want to do

```
:echo GetStringUnderCursor()
```

and see

```
this string has spaces
```

---

EDIT:
I see you can check if the cursor is on a string region with this incantation

```
synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."), col("."), 1)), "name") == "String"
```

I just haven't found a way to look up the start and end positions (line and col) for a given syntax region.

Answer (score 2):

For example :

```
vi"    ->    visual select all inside the quotes
ci"    ->    change all inside the quotes
yi"    ->    yank all inside the quotes
```

If you yank it, you can do :

```
echo @"    ->     prints register " (default)
```

Comment: That's the right idea. Since it's for a vim script and not normal editing, I'd prefer not to clobber a register. Maybe I could settle for clobbering a less frequently used register...